# Aggregating a dataframe by a group of columns passed as arguments

Tags: r, data.table, multiple-columns, aggregation

I have a dataframe which contains feature set for a person at a different times of the day. I want to aggregate it for different durations of time i.e. 1 hr, 2 hr, and so on. I have written this function as follows.

```
 library(data.table)

 getAggregate <- function(comb,limb) {
      comb[Limb == as.character(limb),
      c(fb(BC),
      structure(lapply(.SD,mean),names=meanFeatures),
      structure(lapply(.SD,ivar),names=varFeatures)
      )
     ,by=.(Person,hour(Date),yday(Date),wday(Date))
     ,.SDcols = sigfeats]
 }
```

I just want to pass "Person,hour(Date),yday(Date),wday(Date)" as arguments to the function just like "limb" so that it can aggregate using these four values (or any other values incase the arguments are different).

Comment: Can anyone give me a hint what to do. I have tried to pass the column names as feat1<-c("PatientID","hour(StartClock)","yday(StartDate)","wday(StartDate)") and then passed it to the getAggregate() function. I modified  ,by=.(eval(parse(text=feat1))) but it aggregates by the first column name only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this would work like this...

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)

getAggregate <- function(comb, limb, byList) {
    comb$Hour <- hour(comb$Date)
    comb$YDay <- yday(comb$Date)
    comb$WDay <- wday(comb$Date)
    comb$Minute <- minute(Date)

    comb[Limb == as.character(limb),
         c(
             fb(BC),
             structure(lapply(.SD, mean), names = meanFeatures),
             structure(lapply(.SD, ivar), names = varFeatures)
         )
         , by = byList
         , .SDcols = sigfeats]
}
```

...and you would call the function like so...

```
getAggregate(comb, limb, byList = c("Person", "Hour", "YDay", "WDay", "Minute"))
```

Comment: I also  have to pass the aggregation mechanism i.e. day, wday or hour as argument. Moreover, the number of arguments in by=. (Person, hour(Date), yday(Date), wday(Date)) can change i.e. it can only be by=.(Person) in another case

Comment: I tried the modified version of your answer but it is giving me this error: unused arguments (by = byList, .SDcols = sigfeats). I guess some how the "byList" is not recognized and is not used as an argument

Comment: I want to modify the above mentioned code to extract the number of observations that are aggregated for an hour. For example: we have 12 five minute observations for hour 1

Comment: Do you have a "time" in your `comb` data table?

Comment: Yes i do have the time as "Comb$Date" and Date has the format YMD/HMS